# Android app fail to install in emulator due to missing .env file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, react-native, environment-variables, build.gradle

After cloning and installing a repository, running `npx react-native run-android` returns the error

```
    Configure project :app
    Reading env from: .env
    **************************
    *** Missing .env file ****
    **************************
    FAILURE: Build completed with 1 failure.

    1: Task failed with an exception.
    -----------
    * Where:
    Build file '/home/test/android/app/build.gradle' line: 134

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > Build Config field cannot have a null parameter
```

On line 134, there's nothing that indicates a build config field. I think it's a problem with my local setup. I've checked that I have all the android packages and my paths are correct. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you need to create the `.env` file? Some times this files are not included within the project files, ask what you need to put in it